# Handling ASCII characters in a char to QString conversion

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a bit of trouble with converting a char to QString, as it keeps dumping ASCII characters instead of the sum I would like to be in its hex byte form (e.g. `ffd0`).

---

A bit of a walk through of the code I have - I have a string of hex values (`A1-B2-C3`), which is in a QByteArray and is operated on by a checkSum function I have created. The output is a checksum byte (`ffd0`) and it is printed properly on the terminal with `printf("%x", checkSum(output));`
but when I am using the ui functions of Qt, it prints out rubbish.

What is the most efficient way of doing this on the Qt Creator?

---

Here is some extra clarification:

**Input:**

```
A1-B2-C3
```

**Output:**

Label - "￐"(Nonsenical ascii and, sometimes, the ocasional katakana and hiragana, purely depending on the inputted hex)

printf - `ffd0` (Which is the proper output and the one that I would like set as the text of the label and lineEdit)

---

Code Bit:

```
char MainWindow::checkSum(QByteArray &b)
{
    char val = 0x00;
    char i;
    foreach (i, b)
    {
       val ^= i;
    }

    return val;
}
```

---

```
...

 QChar resultCh =  checkSum(output);

        ui->lineEdit->setText(resultCh);
        ui->outputLabel->setText(resultCh);

        printf("%x\n", resultCh);
...
```

Comment: The problem is that your checkSum is not really a character.  It's a signed integer that is 8 bits long.  You need to convert that signed integer into a text string - not treat it as a Unicode character (which is what you are doing at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct result is not `ffd0` but `d0`.

Why copying `char` to `QChar`?
If, for some reason, you still want to do this, you should convert it to its unicode value before using it:

```
printf("%x", resultCh.unicode());
```

and:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(QString("%1").arg(resultCh.unicode(), 0, 16));
```

Note that `printf("%x", resultCh);` should give you a big warning while compiling.